# How to change a primitive's properties after creating it?

Tags: modeling

I want to model a pistol like this for my FPS:

[image]

You can see how the cylinder for the front of the barrel is very low poly. How do I make a cylinder less low poly? Or even a sphere, anything?

Comment: What's the point of marking something as a duplicate if you don't link to the other item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit the polycount of cylinder by playing with the "Vertices"-setting in this interface:

[image: New Cylinder]

Press <kbd>T</kbd> if you don't see this after Adding a new Cylinder.

Comment: As an aside, this only works immediately after adding a new cylinder. You can't use this to modify existing geometry.

Comment: Yes but in this case, where low poly is wanted it is much faster edding a new Cylinder than editing existing ones. Also the editing part has been answered countless times? I think so.

Comment: Agreed. I just thought it best to mention this for the OP in case they don't already know this. This way they won't have to search for why the redo menu is missing :)

Comment: While the general title suggests a duplicate question about editing "long-gone" mesh properties... If you want to smooth out a cylinder that already exists, you should use the "Subsurface" modifier and adjust the flat end "mean creases" to 1. You can then bump up the "level" of subsurfacing.